# Wrong Jest package in Intellij IDEA run configuration detected

Tags: testing, intellij-idea, jestjs

I want to run the tests of my frontend project, but everytime I want to start a test I get the following error:

[image: Log]

In the Run Configurations, IntelliJ selected `@angular/cli` as default Jest package, which is wrong.

[image: Wrong Jest package]

The correct Jest package should be `jest`.
After I select the correct package, Jest works and runs the selected test.

[image: Correct Jest package]

I have to do this, everytime I want to run a test.
This is not a local problem, my coworkers have the same problem in this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try editing **Jest** run configuration [template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration.html#templates): choose the desired *Jest package* there, save the configuration. New configurations created from gutter/right-click menus will use these settings, you won't need to care of specifying them for each configuration